# CreateView not saving form Django

Tags: python, django

im new to Django. Im creating a bidding site, where users should be able to visit a page to create a new listing (item that they are going to put up).The form that they are required to submit has a few common fields and when valid, the said form should be saved.

Problem is, my listingcreateview() is not doing that. I submit a correct form but it wont save, it just redirects to the same form page and No errors are shown.

This because the submitted form is validated as invalid every time. I know this because of the two functions i added inside listingcreateview(), the second one is called.

It was working properly before, dont know what changes messed it up. If i add in the admin interface information by hand, it is saved successfully.

views.py:

```
class ListingCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Listing
    fields = ['title', 'content', 'image', 'min_bid', 'categories']

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.seller = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
```

models.py:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass


class Listing(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=False, upload_to='media')
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    categories = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices = category)
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE) ##
    min_bid = models.FloatField(blank=False)

    image_thumbnail = ImageSpecField(source='image', processors=[ResizeToFill(300, 150)], format='JPEG', options={'quality':100})

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('listing-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

listing_form.html:

```
{% extends "auctions/layout.html" %}

{% block body %}

    <h2> Create Listing </h2>

    {% if message %}
        <div>{{ message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

{% if messages %}
<div class="alert alert-warning" role="alert">
{{ messages }}
</div>
{% endif %}

<div class="container">
    <form method="POST" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
      <label class="label">{{ form.title.label }}</label>
      <div class="input">{{ form.title }}</div>
      <label class="label">{{ form.content.label }}</label>
      <div class="input">{{ form.content }}</div>
      <label class="label">{{ form.image.label }}</label>
      <div class="input">{{ form.image }}</div>
      <label class="label">Minimal bid</label>
      <div class="input">{{ form.min_bid }}</div>
      <label class="label">{{ form.categories.label }}</label>
      <div class="input">{{ form.categories }}</div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

urls.py:

```
path("create-listing",  login_required(ListingCreateView.as_view()), name="create-listing")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form is invalid because form is missing
enctype="multipart/form-data" which is needed for file uploads

Comment: that did the job, thanks!! How come some hours ago it was working fine even without it?

Comment: Happened to me a lot,file uploads in django are usually potential headaches 